# App running HTTP Server immediately stops listening to requests when opens Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfnetwork

I've implemented a HTTP server on my app using `CFNetwork`.
The server is started at some point to listen to requests via `NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification`.
It's working well if the requests are made when the app is active.
The problem is when I open Safari from my app to load a page provided by this server: The app goes to background and freezes. Safari seems to be waiting for the response, but the response only comes if I go back to the app.
How can I keep the server listening for these requests for some time after it switches to Safari and enters background? Or how would be a best way to implement a HTTP server to work like that? I only need it to open the page on Safari and then stop running.

Comment: Am I getting this right, that you want to implement a (web) server in an iOS app? If so, the bad news for you is that it won't be able to accept any requests when the app is in the background.

Comment: Background operations in iOS are accessible only in a very limited way, responding to HTTP requests is not part of the capabilities.

Comment: I don't really want it to be listening to the requests in background. I just need it to open a page on Safari. I've tested using iOS 7 and it's working well. It switches to Safari and has time enough to respond to the request before actually entering background.
When I try the same in another device with iOS 5, the app goes to background before receiving the request (it actually works some times). Is there a way to delay the app going to background just for a second, so it would be able to receive the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a very simple way to make it work.

I'm creating a background task when the app is entering background.

Just added the following code to `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

```
  __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask =
      [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^
  {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
      [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
  }];
```